# How to train tiny yolov2 with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, tensorflowsharp

I just downloaded tensorflow sharp plugin for unity and tried it with a pre-trained yolov2 model. Now, I want to train my own model to detect a certain kind of object.

What should I do? Do I have to learn 'tensorflow' ? What "training yolov2 with tensorflow" really means?

I found a good article here: https://timebutt.github.io/static/how-to-train-yolov2-to-detect-custom-objects/

But if I'm not wrong, It trains with darknet, not tensorflow. So I think I can't use the output with tensorflowsharp plugin. I couldn't find any straightforward tutorial about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you have to do:

YoloV2 algorithm written in Darknet. Darknet is an open source neural network framework written in C and CUDA. If you want to use YoloV2 with unity tensorflowsharp plugin, you need a Tensorflow implementation of YoloV2.

And [darkflow](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow). (Darknet+Tensorflow=Darkflow. Funny huh?) does the job. So, here is the outline of what you should do to train your own yolov2 algorithm to use in unity with tensorflow:

1. Install anaconda and python environment with tensorflow
2. Download darkflow from github
3. Train yolov2 with darkflow
4. Convert training files to .pb, then .bytes
5. Use .bytes with tensorflowsharp

For the first 3 steps, I strongly recommend video series starting with this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyjBd7IDYZs